# Is there a way to keep the same email template for dark mode too - Outlook and Gmail - Android/IOS

Tags: outlook, gmail, html-email, darkmode, lightmode

I tried the below code:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light" />
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light" />
```

But it still changes email template when I turned on Dark mode from phone. I want to stop changing the template when themes are changed from mobile phones (mainly from iPhone and Android-Phone). The logo and images look so bad in dark mode and also, I have used a color-gradient that also looks so bad in mobile view when I turned on the Dark mode. So, I want the template not to change according to themes.

I am glad if you guys can help me out with this!

Comment: THis has been answered before (the answer is "no, but...") but start here https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the best way to handle dark mode logos in html emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71929609/the-best-way-to-handle-dark-mode-logos-in-html-emails)

Comment: See alos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73107007/html-email-background-color-is-not-displayed-in-gmail-mobile-ios-dark-mode

Comment: And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73461281/force-text-color-in-gmail-ios-on-dark-background-using-mailchimp